# How to use 2-3 lines command in imacro variables?

Tags: imacros

Normally we can use variable in imacro using SET tag, such as

```
SET myDelay 10
WAIT SECONDS={{myDelay}}
```

I need to know, is there any way to use 5-10 lines in a variable. Such as:

```
WAIT SECONDS=25
URL GOTO=........
WAIT SECONDS=15
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 15
```

I want to use whole the above code in a variable. Cause i need to use those line many times in a macro script and i need to change also those lines. So its tough to change every line every time. If i could use a variable then it will easier for me to change only the variable and all the rest data will be working according to this variable.

OR if you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: I haven't seen anything similar to what you ask. But in JS scripting you can use array and that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i also hope so cause i searched a lot, but could not find out.

Comment: searching for same  hope someone answers